# C# URL encoding (net481)

Tags: c#, url, urlencode

I try to build a search query for a movie website, and me being a European we have a bit of weird characters.

This is my starting code:

```
private static string GetSearchUrl(string name)
{
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("https://www.themoviedb.org/search");
    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
    query.Add("query", name);
    uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
    var searchUrl = uriBuilder.ToString();
    return searchUrl;
}
```

these are my test cases:

```
const string Source = "Zur Hölle mit den Paukern";
const string Source = "Astérix & Obélix";
```

When I create a unit test library in `net6.0` everything is very fine, the results are:

```
https://www.themoviedb.org:443/search?query=Zur+H%c3%b6lle+mit+den+Paukern
https://www.themoviedb.org:443/search?query=Ast%c3%a9rix+%26+Ob%c3%a9lix
```

However, running the very same function in my target framework `net481` I get

```
https://www.themoviedb.org:443/search?query=Zur+H%u00f6lle+mit+den+Paukern
https://www.themoviedb.org:443/search?query=Ast%u00e9rix+%26+Ob%u00e9lix
```

The `ö` character is encoded as `%c3%b6` in `net6.0` but as `%u00f6` in `net481`.
The `é` is encoded as `%c3%a9` in `net6.0` but as `%u00e9` in `net481`.
And that doesn't work as a call URL (at least not on themoviedb.org)

I tried encoding as converting from UTF-8 to Windows-1252 first:

```
var win1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(name));
query.Add("query", win1252);
```

But it made no difference.

I also toyed with `Uri.EscapeDataString()` in various places but it usually made it worse.

In `net6.0` the actual type behind the `query` is

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
{System.Web.HttpUtility.HttpQSCollection}
```

In `net481` it is

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
{System.Web.HttpValueCollection}
```

but these are internal implementations returned by the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` call

Comment: `Uri.EscapeDataString()` appears to give the same output in both .NET 4.7.2 and .NET 6 on DotNetFiddle: [.NET 4.7.2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zs8XB5), [.NET 6](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wciw81)...

Comment: @HereticMonkey but if you do `query.Add("query", Uri.EscapeDataString(name));` it gets much worse in the end and I would have preferred to keep the `query` builder class

Comment: The query builder will do its own escaping, which apparently differs between .NET 4.8.1 and .NET 6. Your choice as far as what's more important.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah I guess so, thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77082897/c-sharp-url-encoding-net481#comment135888988_77082897) I decided to code my own version of the QueryBuilder which works for my purposes in `net6.0` and `net481`:

```
public sealed class HttpGetQueryBuilder
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _queryParameters;

    public HttpGetQueryBuilder()
    {
        _queryParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public static HttpGetQueryBuilder ParseQueryString(string query)
    {
        var instance = new HttpGetQueryBuilder();
        var keyValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
        foreach (var key in keyValues.AllKeys)
        {
            instance.Add(key, keyValues[key]);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get => _queryParameters[key];
        set => _queryParameters[key] = value;
    }

    public void Add(string key, string value)
        => _queryParameters.Add(key, value);

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var keyIndex = 0;
        foreach (var keyValue in _queryParameters)
        {
            queryBuilder.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(keyValue.Key));
            queryBuilder.Append('=');
            queryBuilder.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(keyValue.Value));
            keyIndex++;
            if (keyIndex < _queryParameters.Count)
            {
                queryBuilder.Append('&');
            }
        }
        return queryBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```